# Django ChoiseField validation

Tags: django-forms, django-views

I have simple form witch has options for delivery; pickup and post it. There is also possibility to use discount coupons. When using coupons user will always have to go and pay in person with the coupons.

My problem is that when trying to force this behavior and change radio choices when using coupongs in form **clean** it will change **form.cleaned_data** but view will render form with original selection.

```
#forms.py
class DeliveryOptionsForm(forms.Form):
    RADIO_CHOICES = (
       ('pickup',"Pick your stuff from office")),
       ('postit', "send to me by mail (+2€)"),
    )

    delivery = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, 
                           choices=RADIO_CHOICES,
                           help_text=_('Select shipping method'))
    discount = forms.DecimalField(help_text=_('DISCOUNT TICKET'), required=False)

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if 'discount' in data:            
            if data['discount'] == None:
                data['discount'] = 0;
            else:
                #force pickup when putting discount coupongs
                data['pickup'] = 'pickup'
        return data
```

And my view

```
def purchase_confirmation(req):
    cart = req.session['cart']
    form = DeliveryOptionsForm(req.POST or None, initial={'pickup': 'postit'})         

    if req.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():         
        discount = form.cleaned_data['discount']
        pickup = form.cleaned_data['pickup'] 
        # pickup will be correctly set, for logic, 
        # but form will render selection unchanged
        #Some logic here
        .... 
        if 'confirm' in req.POST:
            return redirect('shop-generating_bill')

        if 'update' in req.POST:   
            pass

    return render(req,"confirmation.html",{'form' : form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of your issue but, in your clean method you should get the cleaned data by calling the clean method of the super class.

```
 cleaned_data = super(DeliveryOptionsForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: I tried this, but this had no effect.. thank's still pointing this out.